# How to open and modify Group Policy settings in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, group-policy

How to open and modify Group Policy settings in Windows 8.1? In Windows 7 it's so easy. Search Group Policy in the Start menu and it's done, but in Windows 8.1 it sucks. Even `gpedit.exe` and `gpedit.msc` aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

The *Group policy settings Editor* are only available in the Pro or Enterprise Edition, not in the basic / Core Edition. So make sure you use the Pro Edition.

Comment: Some relevant info, took one Google search. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/41994437-277b-4598-b54e-563f27edc4e8/gpeditmsc-missing-window-8

Answer (score 0):

If you press the windows key, it goes to the start menu.  Start typing group and Edit Group Policy is the first option that comes up.